# Next Js deployment horizontal Scaling Using docker fails on enabling multiple pods

Tags: docker, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, next.js, horizontal-scrolling

We have our application in Next JS that is deployed using Docker and Kubernetes Google Cloud Platform .
The problem that we are facing is -

1. When dockerized and deployed in 1 pod the application works perfectly .
2. When the number of pods are increased to a higher number , the JS and CSS could not be loaded.
3. The path to the JS and CSS files are having a garbage value appended at the URL.

Please find the code to my docker file and yaml files respectively.

```
FROM node:10


# Setting working directory. All the path will be relative to WORKDIR
WORKDIR /app

ENV NODE_ENV=prod
ENV NODE_OPTIONS=--max_old_space_size=4096

# Installing dependencies
COPY ./.npmrc ./
COPY ./package*.json ./

# Copying source files
RUN npm install

COPY ./ ./

RUN echo $pdp_search_key
RUN NODE_ENV=production npm run build

ENTRYPOINT [ "npm" ]
# Running the app
CMD [ "run", "prod-start" ]
```

And the deployment.yaml file is as under -

```
# Default values for helm.
# This is a YAML-formatted file.
# Declare variables to be passed into your templates.

replicaCount: 1

image:
  repository: gcr.io/loblaw-gcr/pc-development
  pullPolicy: Always

nameOverride: ""
fullnameOverride: "pcca-staging"
environment: "staging"

service:
  type: ClusterIP
  port: 80

container:
  port: 80
  healthcheckport: 80
  readinesspath: /ready
  livenesspath: /live

gateway:
  host: pcca-staging.loblaw.digital
  name: pcca-staging
  sso: false

virtualService:
  name: pcca-staging

vault:
  enabled: true
  vaultAddress: https://vault.prod.lblw.cloud:8200
  vaultAuthPath: auth/bluenose/login
  vaultRole: pc_ca-reader-bluenose
  vaultSecretsPath: pc_ca/data/application

resources:
# The following values were ripped from the OMS project and do not reflect any informed decisions
# about what resources our app actually needs - I just had to use something as an example. We need
# to do further testing to make this more meaninful and accurate...
# https://gitlab.lblw.ca/grocery/fulfilment/oms/order/blob/master/helm/oms/values.yaml#L119
  limits:
    cpu: "3"
    memory: "8Gi"
  requests:
    cpu: "1"
    memory: "2512Mi"

autoscaling:
  enabled: true
  minReplicas: 2
  maxReplicas: 2
  averageCPUUtilization: 50
  averageMemoryUtilization: 50

nodeSelector: {}

tolerations: []

affinity: {}
```

Comment: there could be an issue from the code side, ideally, it should not happen. is application using the gzip or any way storing the session store ?

Comment: @Payel Dutta Please open you application, and run inspect element to your browser. Do you see any errors? How about in the back end logs? Please update your question with more detail.